# Update ImageSource return <<Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views>> .Net7 Net Maui

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, imagesource

i need your help to know where i'm wrong..

I have a ContentPage with a listview populated by TextCell only.
When i tap on an element it will invoke the command OpenPostEvent and it will update an image field inside a stacklayout.
The image is generated by an ImageSource, like this:

```
<Image  BackgroundColor="Transparent"  Margin="20" HorizontalOptions="Center"  HeightRequest="130"  Aspect="AspectFit"  Source="{Binding imageSource}"></Image>
```

When i tap on an item into listview i invoke a command in the viewmodel:

```
private void OpenPostEvent(object itemchoose)
{
        Post post = (Post)itemchoose;            
        byte[] immagineByte = post.immaginePostByte;
        streamImmagine = new MemoryStream(immagineByte);
        imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => streamImmagine);            
}
```

First time i tap an item in the listview the image is updating, then if i tap on another element on listview i get the error..
How i can retrieve the mainthread?

I used Davice.BeginInvokeOnMainThread but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in set imageSource variable to null before reload with new stream...

```
private void OpenPostEvent(object itemchoose)
{
        Post post = (Post)itemchoose;            
        byte[] immagineByte = post.immaginePostByte;
        streamImmagine = new MemoryStream(immagineByte);
        imageSource = null;
        imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => streamImmagine);            
}
```